# Execute windows command from python3.4

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, python-3.4

I have a command which I use for deployment from windows command line. Now I need to run the same from an external python3.4 script.

The command is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild "D:\WebService\WebService.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="D:\WebService\Properties\PublishProfiles\MyDeployment.pubxml" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName=name /p:Password=PASSWORD`.

How can I achieve this. I tried `subprocess` . But it's not working.Please help me out.

Comment: `I tried subprocess. But it's not working` <- Exactly how? Show us exactly what you tried

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I tried `subprocess.call("C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild "D:\WebService\WebService.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="D:\WebService\Properties\PublishProfiles\MyDeployment.pubxml" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName=name /p:Password=PASSWORD")`. It gives me syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems appear to be the `\` and `"` characters, so use raw strings.  Also, it is safer to use a list:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild",
             r"D:\WebService\WebService.sln",
             r"/p:DeployOnBuild=true",
             r"/p:PublishProfile=D:\WebService\Properties\PublishProfiles\MyDeployment.pubxml",
             r"/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true",
             r"/p:UserName=name",
             r"/p:Password=PASSWORD"])

proc.wait()
```

Strictly speaking you don't need raw strings for all those parameters, but it is safer to do so with Windows paths.  <s>You only need the internal double quotes if you have embedded whitespace (as the first parameter).</s>  Here we are not using a shell, set `shell=True` as a parameter if you need one.  A reason to use a shell on Windows is for filename association, but you don't appear to be using that here.

Comment: Is it possible to give relative path in this answer if I have the present working directory stored in a variable `pwd`

Comment: @NevinRaj: depends how you use it.  Generally yes, all filenames can be relative and the current working directory is inherited (by default) by the child process, so you won't need `pwd`.  However some programs require absolute paths, and often you cant be sure what the working directory will be, depending on the user.

Comment: Don't add quotes manually. `subprocess.Popen` calls `subprocess.list2cmdline` to handle this for you. This function assumes the `argv` parsing rules implemented by Microsoft's C runtime and [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391). *Most* Windows programs adhere to these rules. If a program has its own rules for parsing the command line you'll have to pass the command as a string.

Comment: @eryksun: you are correct, but they are need if `shell=True`.

Comment: @cdarke: `cmd.exe` (`%COMSPEC%` -- the shell) uses different rules (e.g., `^` is an escape character) but you still do not need the quotes in this case.

Comment: On Windows, `Popen` uses `args = list2cmdline(args)` even for a `shell` command, so just never add quotes manually with a list. That said, you shouldn't use a list for a `shell` command. On POSIX systems it's unlikely to be what you want (the parameters are passed to the shell itself, and used as `$0`, `$1`, etc). On Windows, cmd.exe has its own quirky rules for quoting and escaping, and Python doesn't currently have a function to implement cmd's 'logic' (tortured as it is).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code with what you have tried so far?

The subprocess module should be able to handle that, with something like

```
theproc = subprocess.Popen(["COMMAND HERE"])
theproc.communicate()
```

or you could try with the shell flag

```
theproc = subprocess.Popen(["COMMAND HERE"], shell=True)
```

Comment: I tried `theproc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild "D:\WebService\WebService.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="D:\WebService\Properties\PublishProfiles\MyDeployment.pubxml" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:UserName=Admin /p:Password=me@321"])`
                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Can you try `theproc = subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild \"  D:\WebService\WebService.sln\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=\"D:\We  bService\Properties\PublishProfiles\MyDeployment.pubxml\" /p:AllowUntrustedCer  tificate=true /p:UserName=Admin /p:Password=me@321") 
  theproc.communicate()`
Your command string has multiple double quotes, so the string ends before you want it to.